# PowerShell Boolean

Tags: powershell, boolean

```
    $e = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference="stop"
    $E_Subnet_1 = '10.0.1'
    $E_Subnet_2 = '10.0.2'
    $O_Subnet_1 = '10.11.1'
    $O_Subnet_2 = '10.11.2'
    $D_Subnet_1 = '10.12.1'
    $D_Subnet_2 = '10.12.2'
    $Ethernet0 = 'Ethernet0'
    $All_Subnets = @("$E_Subnet_1", "$E_Subnet_2", "$O_Subnet_1",
                     "$O_Subnet_2", "$D_Subnet_1", "$D_Subnet_2")

    $result = (Get-NetAdapter |
                    ? status -eq 'up' |
                    Get-NetIPAddress -ErrorAction 0 |
                    ? PrefixOrigin -eq 'Manual' |
                    ? IPAddress -match $All_Subnets |
                   foreach { $Ethernet0 -eq $_.InterfaceAlias})

    Write-Host "interface_alias=$result"
```

If you will please consider the PowerShell snippet above which queries the network interfaces and based on the matching subnet it then checks if the interface name equals "Ethernet0" producing a boolean value.

The IPAddress of the server I am currently working matches the first three octets of `$D_Subnet_1` and produces a value of `interface_alias=True` if I target `$D_Subnet_1` like this:

```
    $result = (Get-NetAdapter |
                    ? status -eq 'up' |
                    Get-NetIPAddress -ErrorAction 0 |
                    ? PrefixOrigin -eq 'Manual' |
                    ? IPAddress -match $D_Subnet_1 |
                    foreach { $Ethernet0 -eq $_.InterfaceAlias})

    Write-Host "interface_alias=$result"
```

But if I try to run the command using the `$All_Subnets` array:

```
    $result = (Get-NetAdapter |
                    ? status -eq 'up' |
                    Get-NetIPAddress -ErrorAction 0 |
                    ? PrefixOrigin -eq 'Manual' |
                    ? IPAddress -match $All_Subnets |
                    foreach { $Ethernet0 -eq $_.InterfaceAlias})

    Write-Host "interface_alias=$result"
```

It just produces `interface_alias=` with no value at all.

I have tried swapping `-match` for `-contain` and `like` with no luck. How can I fix this?

Comment: `-contains` is for comparing an array to a single item.  You're looking for the `-in` comparison operator.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I failed to mention `-in` doesn't work either.

Comment: After looking at your code more, you're going to need a real scriptblock for that comparison: `?{$_.IPAddress.Substring(0,$_.IPAddress.LastIndexOf('.') -in $All_Subnets}`

Comment: This bit of your pipe ***IPAddress -match $All_Subnets*** does not make sense. You are asjing if a string matches an array. They are not even the same data type.

Comment: @EBGreen I mean, technically they're strings.  One's just an array of strings.  My comment should address his question, so I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: The key point is that it is an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong comparisons here:

```
Where-Object -Property 'IPAddress' -Match @('10.30.2','10.40.2')
```

You need to grab the first 3 octets to do this comparison properly:

```
Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.IPAddress.Substring(0, $_.IPAddress.LastIndexOf('.')) -in $All_Subnets }
```

And if you're not on version 3+, just swap the comparison's sides and change the operator to `-contains`

Comment: This works! I wish I understood this a little better. I will research it all a bit more.
Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Rob If this answered your question, kindly mark it as such with the green checkmark.  What doesn't make sense to you? I can try to explain.

Comment: Would you mind explaining swapping the comparison sides?

Comment: @Rob `$All_Subnets -contains $_.IPAddress.Substring(0, $_.IPAddress.LastIndexOf('.'))`  Version 2 of PowerShell did not have the `-in` operator yet.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell has two operators which work with collections: `-contains` and `-in`.

The other operators, I think all of them, can't work with collections but PowerShell pretends they can. They can be used for two types of matching - "*compare these two single things with each other and output a result*", which is `$a -eq $z` or `$a -match $z` and the output is a boolean true/false - did it work?

And it can do "*compare this collection of things against this single thing and output filter the collection to only the things that worked*". This is `($a, $b, $c) -eq $z` or `($a, $b, $c) -match $z` and the output is the things for which the test worked: `($b, $c)`. Specifically, collection on the left, single thing on the right.

What is tripping you up is that `-match` does a regex test, and regular expressions can match substrings. So your direct subnet test is doing `"10.0.1.2" -match "10.0.1"` and it works. But your second attempt to use the array is going all wrong because putting the array on the right changes what happens:

```
IPAddress -match $All_Subnets
```

turns into "-match works with a regular expression on the right, the array gets cast to a string, it's joined together with a space between each item, and becomes: `10.0.1 10.0.2 10.11.1 10.11.2 10.12.1 10.12.2`

And now you have `"10.0.1.2" -match "10.0.1 10.0.2 10.11.1 10.11.2 10.12.1 10.12.2"` which it doesn't.

This also explains why `-in` and `-contains` don't work - because they are *not* doing regular expression tests, and cannot match substrings. They look for whether the IPAddress is in the list of subnets exactly - which it isn't, because they have no last octet.

@TheIncorrigible1's answer works around this by converting the IP address to just the first three octets, then looking for that in the array, which it a test that can work.

Another approach would be to loop over the contents of the array and test each one. e.g.

```
? { $All_Subnets | foreach { $IPAddress -match $_ } } |
```

"Where (there is any output from testing each subnet against the IP)".

This assumes that all your subnets are /24 which may or may not be good.

You could instead change your array to include network addresses and subnet masks and do a "proper" subnet check, e.g. something like http://get-powershell.com/post/2010/01/29/Determining-if-IP-addresses-are-on-the-same-subnet.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this very well written information, it is very much appreciated. Once I get my reputation above 15 I'll come back and upvote all.